# Windows Universal App - In-app product for Windows 8.1 not working

Tags: windows, product, win-universal-app, in-app

My app is already published on the Windows Store and Windows Phone Store. The consumable in-app products are working for Windows Phone but not for Windows.

This code does not work for example:

```
var listing = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
```

it gives this exception:

```
HRESULT: 0x801900CC
```

And when I want to purchase a in-app product, it tells me that this app is not found in Windows Store. But it is already published today and I can download it from the store.

I am doing this like in MSDN documentation and it is the exact same code for the Windows Phone version and there it works. I had to deactivate in-app purchasing in Windows 8.1 app because otherwise it wouldn't pass certification because of this problem. The in-app products are well defined in the store during submission. And the app has correct name and publisher infos in Visual STudio 2013.

So do you know the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems like you have to make sure that in app products don't crash even when no internet connection or server is down or app not published yet. Because otherwise the certification will not activate the products even when they were defined before submitting. Only when you handle exceptions and the app doesn't crash they activate your in app products.